# PING: transmit failed. General failure. – short outage every few minutes

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, lenovo-laptop, wifi-transfer

Every few minutes, there is a temporary outage on Wi-Fi interface of my Lenovo Yoga X1 20FR laptop.
The following output from `ping` command documents one such occurrence. Every second a new line is added so you can see how long the problem typically occurs.

```
ping 192.168.1.1 -t  (this is a router to which the laptop is connected)
---------------------
...
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=9ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=6ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=383ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=233ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=289ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=6ms TTL=64
PING: transmit failed. General failure.
PING: transmit failed. General failure.
PING: transmit failed. General failure.
PING: transmit failed. General failure.
PING: transmit failed. General failure.
PING: transmit failed. General failure.
General failure.
General failure.
General failure.
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=34ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=32ms TTL=64
...
```

The failure reoccurs exactly every 10 minutes.
In Event log System, the following two messages are seen:

```
• Name resolution for the name _ldap._tcp.Site-AAAA-RA._sites.dc._msdcs.AAAA.com. timed out after none of the configured DNS servers responded.  (AAAA-real name masked)
• NtpClient was unable to set a domain peer to use as a time source because of discovery error. NtpClient will try again in 15 minutes and double the reattempt interval thereafter. The error was: The entry is not found. (0x800706E1)
```

It looks to me like something is "playing" with Wi-Fi network adapter and the above two messages are just consequences of its reinitialization.

What is causing this and how it can be fixed?

Comment: Check your cable connection. It may be loosen. Or the proximity of your devices.

Comment: @Biswa – Interrupted connections report timeouts, not general failures.

Comment: "General failure" occurs when no network interfaces are available to handle IP traffic. What's being logged  in the System event log?

Comment: @Twisty – thank you for additional questions. I put the answers into the question.

Comment: You're correct that the two events you found are just consequence events. Are there no events from your Wi-Fi network driver when these other events are logged?

Comment: @Twisty – I found the answer. Looks like our IT department is using some cool script with not so cool side effects. I added some general information to answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regaular schedule of failures led me to examine the Task Scheduler and in this case, one of its tasks (a custom task) was the culprit.

This seems to be some PowerShell script installed by my employer's IT. I found a task in the Task Scheduler with *Last Run Time* always corresponding to time of most recent failure. I'll just adjust it for now, but generally, it is a time to raise a ticket with the IT.

UPDATE: Later I also found that the similar behavior is caused when half of DNS leasing period expires so there is time to renew the leasing. E.g. if DNS leasing period is set to 20 minutes at router, this problem occurs every 10 minutes. I prolonged leasing period to 3 days to mitigate the issue.